# Why "Redirected when going from "/login" to "/" via a navigation guard." is appearing?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, local-storage, vue-router

Here the router guard is working fine on my vue app, but after logging in, the following error appears on console.

> *Uncaught (in promise) Error: Redirected when going from "/login" to "/" via a navigation guard.*

Here is my code snippet.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/login",
    component: () => import("../views/Auth/Login"),
    meta: { hideForAuth: true },
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    component: DashboardLayout,
    meta: { requiresAuth: true },
    children: [
      {
        path: "home",
        name: "Home",
        component: () => import("../views/Home"),
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

The Auth guard:

```
const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem("auth");

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (!loggedIn) {
      next({ path: "/login" });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }

  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.hideForAuth)) {
    if (loggedIn) {
      next({ path: "//" });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Can't figure out the problem. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `next` does not exit the guard, the guard will call `next` a minimum of 2 times per route because you have 2 separate `if` statements and both will run.

- Change the `//` path to `/`
- call `next` like `return next` to exit the function, or structure your `if` statements so that only one will run.
- Set `loggedIn` inside the guard or it will only be evaluated once, when the router is created

Here's one way to do it that also covers routes having no `meta`:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem("auth");
  const isAuth = to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth);
  const isHide = to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.hideForAuth);

  if (isAuth && !loggedIn) {
    return next({ path: "/login" });
  } else if (isHide && loggedIn) {
    return next({ path: "/" });
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem @Dan. still same error showing in the console. In fact an extra refresh in needed now after login, otherwise it's not redirecting to the dashboard ('/' route). Any idea ?

Comment: Now I'm noticing `loggedIn` won't ever change, because it needs to be set inside the guard.  See my update.  As for the error, maybe it's caused by something you didn't show.  Can you post the way you set `loggedIn` and make the first redirect.

Comment: if I get your question correctly then, I am setting an item in local storage like `localStorage.setItem("auth", "true");` and retrieving it before each route path. 

Now, your updated solution is working fine & and my last asking is previous error is showing during logout. I am doing this in logout `this.$router.push({ path: "/login" });`

what's the problem here @Dan ?

Comment: I'm not sure, there's only so many things I can correct without seeing it :)  Did you set auth to false before changing the route?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property home to false in the redirect config, in auth property at **nuxt.config.js** file

```
redirect: {
  login: '/login',
  logout: '/login',
  callback: false,
  home: false
}
```

and then, redirect the login to /

```
async login() {
  try {
    await this.$auth.loginWith('local', { data: this.form })
    this.$router.push('/')
  } catch {
   ...
  }
}
```